# Powerhsell get-qaduser using a select not returning any data

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run some powershell using the plugin from quest `cmdlet` is called `get-qaduser` the syntax for the one liner is

`Get-QADUser -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludeAllProperties -SizeLimit 0 | Where-Object extensionAttribute1 -eq $null`

this works and returns all the users with a blank extensionAttribute1 when i then pipe this to Select and only specify certain properties it just sits at the command prompt and never completes.

`Get-QADUser -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludeAllProperties -SizeLimit 0 | Where-Object extensionAttribute1 -eq $null |
Select Firstname,lastname,ExtensionAttribute1,Samaccountname,mail,Title,DN,Whencreated,
PasswordStatus,PasswordExpires,lastlogon,Accountisdisabled,accountislocked,passwordneverexpires,accountisexpired`

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Executing it in powershell 2.0 (modifying the foreach-object syntax) works for me.

Comment: sorry i don't understand i'm not using the foreach-object

Comment: Oops, I meant `where-object`, sorry.. ;)

Comment: not problem, what did you modify where-object syntax to?

Comment: `Where-Object { $_.extensionAttribute1 -eq $null}` but just because I'm on powershell 2.0. On version 3.0 must be good your code too.

Comment: that works thanks, do you know why it does not work if you dont include the brackets?

Comment: but are you on version 2 or 3 ?

Comment: Does a ">>" appear on the line below the command when you press enter?  Just wondering if PowerShell thinks the command hasn't been completed yet.  If that is the case, press enter again to get the command started.